# Batch File. If user enters something figure out which one it is

Tags: batch-file, runtime-error

So I am making a batch file that opens specific information such as lets say I want to open information in my batch file that requires the users input. Such as File1, File2 & File3.

If the user enters File2 in the user input area I wish to make it go to it this was my first try of code.

```
:loggedin
echo Access Granted
echo Security Level 1
set /p select=Enter Password:%=%
::Checks the file the user is looking for
if "%select%"=="" (
cls
echo !NOTHING WAS INPUT INTO THE CONSOLE TRY AGAIN!
pause
goto :loggedin
) else ( 
if "select"=="file1"(
::User has input the file name. Show the content.
echo "Content of file 1"
) else (
if "select"=="file2"(
echo "Content of file2"
) else (
if "select"=="file3"(
echo "content of file three"
) else (
goto :loggedin
```

I know that this is extremely wrong code but I am having a hard time getting around it I have tried multiple ways and still cant get past it.

Would I use ERRORLEVEL to fix this problem?

Comment: There must be a *space* between the `if` expressions and `(`, like: `if "select"=="file1" (`

Comment: There are 4 closing `)` missing after the very last command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables must be enclosed with `%` or with `!`(in case of delayed expansion).You can also use `/I` switch for `IF`.And there's no else-if construction in bacth files.And in brackets blocks it's safer to use [REM](http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html) as a comment:

```
:loggedin
echo Access Granted
echo Security Level 1
set /p select=Enter Password:%=%
::Checks the file the user is looking for
if "%select%"=="" (
 cls
 echo !NOTHING WAS INPUT INTO THE CONSOLE TRY AGAIN!
 pause
 goto :loggedin
) 

if /I "%select%"=="file1" (
 rem User has input the file name. Show the content.
 echo "Content of file 1"
) 

if /I "%select%"=="file2" (
 echo "Content of file2"
) 

if /i "%select%"=="file3"(
 echo "content of file three"
) 
goto :loggedin
```

Comment: there has to be a space before the `(` - which makes our answers nearly identical :D

Comment: It worked. Thank you For pointing out that there is no else-if. It's been a while and I forgot to look it up. But mostly I was doing plenty things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`else` is sometimes useful, but you don't Need it here:

```
:loggedin
echo Access Granted
echo Security Level 1
set /p select=Enter Password:%=%
::Checks the file the user is looking for
if "%select%"=="" (
  cls
  echo !NOTHING WAS INPUT INTO THE CONSOLE TRY AGAIN!
  pause
)
if /i "%select%"=="file1" (
  ::User has input the file name. Show the content.
  echo "Content of file 1"
)
if /i "%select%"=="file2" (
  echo "Content of file2"
)
if /i "%select%"=="file3" (
  echo "content of file three"
)
goto :loggedin
```

Also: it says "Access granted" and asks you for a Password *afterwards*?

I added `/i` for the `if`'s to make it case insensitive.

Comment: `select` must be `%select%`